# App Crashing (No adapter attached; skipping layout) (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

This is my code and the app is crashing again and again

```
package com.example.bookhub.adapter.fragment

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.DownloadManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.textclassifier.TextClassification
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.example.bookhub.R
import com.example.bookhub.adapter.adapter.DasboardRecyclerAdapter
import com.example.bookhub.adapter.model.Book
import com.example.bookhub.adapter.util.ConnectionManager


class dashboardFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var recyclerDashboard: RecyclerView
    lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    lateinit var btnCheckInternet: Button


    lateinit var recyclerAdapter: DasboardRecyclerAdapter
    lateinit var bookInfoList: ArrayList<Book>
    /*  var bookInfoList = arrayListOf<Book>(
          Book("P.S. I love You", "Cecelia Ahern", "Rs. 299", "4.5", 77777,777),
          Book("The Great Gatsby", "F. Scott Fitzgerald", "Rs. 399", "4.1", R.drawable.great_gatsby),
          Book("Anna Karenina", "Leo Tolstoy", "Rs. 199", "4.3", R.drawable.anna_kare),
          Book("Madame Bovary", "Gustave Flaubert", "Rs. 500", "4.0", R.drawable.madame),
          Book("War and Peace", "Leo Tolstoy", "Rs. 249", "4.8", R.drawable.war_and_peace),
          Book("Lolita", "Vladimir Nabokov", "Rs. 349", "3.9", R.drawable.lolita),
          Book("Middlemarch", "George Eliot", "Rs. 599", "4.2", R.drawable.middlemarch),
          Book("The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn", "Mark Twain", "Rs. 699", "4.5", R.drawable.adventures_finn),
          Book("Moby-Dick", "Herman Melville", "Rs. 499", "4.5", R.drawable.moby_dick),
          Book("The Lord of the Rings", "J.R.R Tolkien", "Rs. 749", "5.0", R.drawable.lord_of_rings)
      )*/

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this com.example.bookhub.com.example.bookhub.adapter.adapter.fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)



        recyclerDashboard = view.findViewById(R.id.recylerDashboard)



        btnCheckInternet = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckInternet)
        btnCheckInternet.setOnClickListener {
            if (ConnectionManager().checkConnectivity(activity as Context)) {
                //internet is available
                val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as Context)
                dialog.setTitle("Success")
                dialog.setMessage("Internet Connection Found")
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok") { text, listner ->

                }
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { text, listner ->

                }

                dialog.create()
                dialog.show()

            } else {
                //internet not available
                val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as Context)
                dialog.setTitle("Error")
                dialog.setMessage("Internet Connection Not Found")
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok") { text, listner ->

                }
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { text, listner ->

                }

                dialog.create()
                dialog.show()
            }
        }

        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)


        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity as Context)

        val url = "http://13.235.250.119/v1/book/fetch_books/"

        val jsonObjectRequest =
            object : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, Response.Listener {
                // Here we will handle the respose
                val success = it.getBoolean("success")
                if (success) {
                    val data = it.getJSONArray("data")
                    for (i in 0 until data.length()) {
                        val bookJsonObject = data.getJSONObject(i)
                        val bookObject = Book(
                            bookJsonObject.getString("book_id"),
                            bookJsonObject.getString("name"),
                            bookJsonObject.getString("author"),
                            bookJsonObject.getString("rating"),
                            bookJsonObject.getString("price"),
                            bookJsonObject.getString("image")

                        )
                        bookInfoList.add(bookObject)
                        recyclerAdapter = DasboardRecyclerAdapter(activity as Context, bookInfoList)

                        recyclerDashboard.adapter = recyclerAdapter
                        recyclerDashboard.layoutManager = layoutManager

                        recyclerDashboard.addItemDecoration(
                            DividerItemDecoration(
                                recyclerDashboard.context,
                                (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).orientation
                            )
                        )


                    }


                } else  {
                    Toast.makeText(activity as Context, "Some ERROR OCCURED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }


            }, Response.ErrorListener {
                // here we handel the error
                println("Error is $it")

            }) {

                override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                    headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
                    headers["token"] = "fe******8a1ec7"
                    return headers
                }

            }

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)


        return view
    }


}
```

It gives error in LOGCAT as

`06-28 17:07:13.983 14675-14675/com.example.bookhub E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

I have added attached the adapter yet it is giving error
and the app crashes every time I run it

I think the error is in the area where I declared **bookInfoList**

or Maybe in the area where I created **jsonObectRequest**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "It gives error in LOGCAT as" -- that is not a crash. If you are crashing, you will get a [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/115145).

Comment: If it crashed , there is an error that shows in the logcat , if you can copy paste whole logcat in pastebin and i ll check it

Comment: @CommonsWare but the app isn't running

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh just Solved it

Comment: The Place where I Declared bookInfoList I changed the Declaration to ``` var bookInfoList = arrayListOf<Book>()```
And that solved it all

Answer (score 0):

I looked little deeper into your code and i assume that the error is happening because you are setting the layoutmanager after setting the adapter  , would you try to reorganize these lines as following :

```
recyclerDashboard.layoutManager = layoutManager
recyclerDashboard.addItemDecoration(
                            DividerItemDecoration(
                                recyclerDashboard.context,
                                (layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).orientation
                            )
                        )
recyclerAdapter = DasboardRecyclerAdapter(activity as Context, bookInfoList)
recyclerDashboard.adapter = recyclerAdapter
```

Comment: Actually I figures out the error 
it was because I had the declaration of **bookInfoList** Was wrongly declared
Its Should be declared As  ```  var   bookInfoList = arrayListOf<book>() ```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your Recyclerview has no adapter when onCreateView completed and response will pass after the view created. so Recyclerview needs an adapter that hasn't. Create an empty adapter and pass it as an adapter to Recyclerview inside the onCreateView.

to make sure the adapter without data won't crash add code below to it.
In your DasboardRecyclerAdapter Overload the getItemCount like this

```
 override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return bookInfoList.size // your data size
}
```

Comment: Actually I figures out the error 
it was because I had the declaration of **bookInfoList** Was wrongly declared
Its Should be declared As  `  var   bookInfoList = arrayListOf<book>() `

Answer (score 0):

Please remove- lateinit var bookInfoList: ArrayListOf

and add-     val bookInfoList= arrayListOf()

The problem will be resolved